# Issue adapting Pine Script statement with nested conditional operators

Tags: pine-script, conditional-operator

Please help with adapting following Pine code into a more readable code with "if", "else", "true" and "false" like in other (script) languages (need it in MQL5) It seems to me as a newbie that "dlong" is a series with boolean values (...if 0 means "false" in this case and >0 "true", right?)

```
dlong = 0
dlong := nz(dlong[1])>0?  elong==1? 0 : dlong[1]+1 : long? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`dlong` is not `bool`, it is an `int`. `bool` variables can have either `true` or `false`. But you can also use int types for if checks. 0 is `false` and everyting else is `true`.

From [?: conditional operator and the iff function](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#conditional-operator-and-the-iff-function):

> The ?: conditional ternary operator calculates the first expression
> (condition) and returns the value of either the second operand (if the
> condition is true) or of the third operand (if the condition is
> false). Syntax is:
>
> `condition ? result1 : result2`

```
dlong = 0

if (nz(dlong[1]) > 0)
    if (elong == 1)
        dlong := 0
    else
        dlong := dlong[1] + 1
else
    if long
        dlong := 1
    else
        dlong := 0
```